# Replace a text within parentheses in R

Tags: r, string

I need to replace a text when it includes `(D)` in it.

Here is the sample:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 text = c("Student was (D) in X","text1","tex2"))

> df
  id                 text
1  1           Student was (D) in X
2  2                text1
3  3                 tex2
```

My desired output would be:

```
> df
      id                 text
    1  1                 Discontinue
    2  2                text1
    3  3                 tex2
```

I need to replace `(D)` with `Discontinue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one more `stringr` option combined with `ifelse`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(text = ifelse(str_detect(text, '(D)'), "Discontinue", text))
```

```
  id        text
1  1 Discontinue
2  2       text1
3  3        tex2
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(text = str_replace(text, '.*\\(D\\).*', 'Discontinue'))
```

-output

```
  id        text
1  1 Discontinue
2  2       text1
3  3        tex2
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `gsub` with `fixed = TRUE` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 text = c("Student was (D) in X","text1","tex2"))

df$text <- gsub("(D)", "Discontinue", df$text, fixed = TRUE)
df
#>   id                         text
#> 1  1 Student was Discontinue in X
#> 2  2                        text1
#> 3  3                         tex2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>